# Xamarin VS: Debugging first project does not show project on emulator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-emulator

Testing out Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017. I have an Android emulator running when I hit the debug to run the program, but my program does not appear on the emulator. Is there some connection issue? If so, where?

Deleting bin folders; creating new project to test; creating new emulator;

Here is the build output:

```
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: (null)
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: (null)
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196608'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.adb.secure' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '256m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '420'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'monodroid.avdname' = 'my_device'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'Unknown/Unknown'
emulator: _hwFingerprint_connect: connect finger print listen is called
audio: Failed to create voice `adc'
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: (null)
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: (null)
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: (null)
UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(780, 216), size=(300x96), dirty=(300x96 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.)
UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect failed for ptDst=(780, 216), size=(300x96), dirty=(300x96 0, 0) (A device attached to the system is not functioning.)
```

Comment: Try switching to another Android version. Right click on your Android project->Properties and set a different version in the "Compile using Android version" section of the dialog window that appears. Make sure you have whatever version of the SDK you are using installed by opening Tools->Android->Android SDK Manager

Comment: Nope that did not work...tried reinstalling visual studio and that's a nope as well.